# How do I create language support files for a new language that is not currently supported by any operating system?

Tags: dictionary, keyboard, operating-system

I am from the Cabo Verde Islands. 
Our language is Caboverdean:
- ISO 639-3kea
- Writing Latin script [Latn].

**Problem:**
It is a chore to type in Caboverdean because hardware devices don't have the language files to support it.

How would one go about to create those files?

Not sure what this entails or what files I need to create, hence the question, but I formulated the following related questions:

- How to create an input language file?
- How to create a keyboard file for a language?
- How to create a dictionary file for a language?

Are these the questions I need to be asking?

Comment: I am so tempted to go and do the job for you for board and beer money.   It would take all summer.

Comment: Board and beer works; you will fall in love with the islands! But your comment also suggests you also have a clue on how this can be done. What type of files are we talking about here? send me a private message and we can arrange your trip.